# Sorting vector of objects by object's variable

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

I have a vector of objects. Each of these objects has 2 fields (the values of which can be repeated), e.g:

```
//myClass name = myClass(x,y)
myClass obj1 = myClass(2,5);
myClass obj2 = myClass(2,4);
myClass obj3 = myClass(1,5);
myClass obj4 = myClass(3,2);
 
std::vector<myClass> myVector;
 
myVector.push_back(obj1);
myVector.push_back(obj2);
myVector.push_back(obj3);
myVector.push_back(obj4);
```

I want to sort the vector. First it should be sorted by 1st values. If the values of the 1st variable is the same, then should be sorted by second variable. Vector after sorting should be like that:

> 1. obj3 //(1,5)
> 2. obj2 //(2,4)
> 3. obj1 //(2,5)
> 4. obj4 //(3,2)

I have wrote this simple code with bubble sort:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < myVector.size() - 1; j++)
        {
            if (myVector[j].x < myVector[j + 1].x)
                std::swap(myVector[j], myVector[j + 1]);
        }
    }
```

Now `myVector` is sorted by first value, but how to sort elements, which first value it the same, by second value? Like in example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < myVector.size() - 1; j++)
        {
            if (myVector[j].x < myVector[j + 1].x)
            {
                std::swap(myVector[j], myVector[j + 1]);
            }
            else if (myVector[j].x == myVector[j + 1].x)
            {
                if (myVector[j].y < myVector[j + 1].y)
                    std::swap(myVector[j], myVector[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may change your if statement to:

```
if ( (myVector[j].x == myVector[j + 1].x) ? (myVector[j].y < myVector[j + 1].y) : (myVector[j].x < myVector[j + 1].x)  )
```

Comment: You're right but i think it's little bit complicated to understand for a novice

Comment: @YannisSauzeau Yeah, this code works, but I really don't understand how...

Comment: look at my code above, you see that the statement `std::swap(myVector[j], myVector[j + 1]);` is the same on both conditions, the only difference is the statement `if (myVector[j].x < myVector[j + 1].x)` that becomes `if (myVector[j].y < myVector[j + 1].y)`  when `myVector[j].x == myVector[j + 1].x`, so you can use [ternary operator](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_conditions_shorthand.asp) to avoid this code duplication. But it's better for you at the beginning to use comprehensive code with duplication, it's for that i propose to use you my code above.

Comment: @armin-montigny I don't find the ternary operator difficult to understand, I use it a lot (especially with Flutter) and of course your solution is better to avoid code duplication, however this operator is often misunderstood by beginners, the proof the author of the question didn't understand your answer

Answer (score 1):

For starters if you want to sort your vector in the ascending order then at least you need to use the if statement the following way

```
        if (myVector[j+1].x < myVector[j].x)
            std::swap(myVector[j], myVector[j + 1]);
```

instead of

```
        if (myVector[j].x < myVector[j + 1].x)
            std::swap(myVector[j], myVector[j + 1]);
```

A simple approach is to use the standard function `std::tie` declared in the header  `<tuple>`.

For example

```
#include <tuple>

//...

for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myVector.size() - 1; j++)
    {
        if ( std::tie( myVector[j+1].x, myVector[j+1].y ) < 
             std::tie( myVector[j].x, myVector[j].y ) )
            std::swap(myVector[j], myVector[j + 1]);
    }
}
```

Instead of the manually written loops you could use the standard algorithm `std::sort`. For example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::sort( std::begin( myVector ), std::end( myVector ),
           []( const auto &obj1, const auto &obj2 )
           {
               return std::tie( obj1.x, obj1.y ) < std::tie( obj2.x, obj2.y );
           } );
```